# Change phone ring volume on a schedule

Tags: 8.1, quiet-hours

I've just switched from Android to Windows Phone. Generally speaking i'm ok with it, but I miss one application from Android. It was [Phone Scheduler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antonc.phone_schedule).

I could schedule there at what time my ring will change into vibrations, when fly mode will be turned on and off, etc.

I didn't found any application in Windows Store that would have similar features.
So I fought that maybe I will write something similar.

Could you please tell me if there is a possibility to do that ?

Comment: This is a development question, therefore it belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: ok, can I move it to StackOverflow or do I have to delete it and repost on StackOverflow?

Comment: This isn't something that can be done by third party app developers (so little point asking on Stack Overflow), but as a consumer you can use quiet hours to do what you describe; have just edited to refocus as a consumer view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you can turn your ringer off at set times is by using Quiet Hours. You can do this by going to Settings > Quiet Hours, turning on Automatic Rules, and setting the times you want your ringer turned off. Unfortunately, this will work only if your region is set to US.

Comment: I've a dillema now, I should mark this as an answer, but this solution works in English culture of windows phone. I use polish culture and therefor it is not available for me... Only solution I can see is to switch to English culture but it's to problematic...

Comment: Unfortunately, there will not be any way for you to achieve this outside of Quiet Hours. Which, as you said, only works if your location is set to US. I'll update my answer to include this info.

Comment: I will mark it as a correct answer, thanks for help :)